# AzureAD rolebased authorization

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

I have my app registered in AzureAdd AppRegistrations, and added `AppRoles` in the `manifest` for my app, the role of Admin. In the Azure Enterprise Application menu, I added a user, and assigned it the Admin role, which I could select.

In the `Startup` class of my application, I added the AddAuthorization part and defined a policy `RequireRole("Admin")`.

I used the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` for my controller class, and in the navbar partial view I added `((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "Admin")).Succeeded)` .

However, when I debug, I cannot find the `{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Admin}` entry, and `User.IsInRole("Admin")` returns false. The user credentials are correct, though.
As far as I can see, I have done all the steps. Only thing that I can come up with is that my azure subscription doesn't allow groups to be added, but I don't see how that could be connected to any of the things I set up. I use no groups, just individual users. 
What am I missing here? Why don't I see the user roles?

Manifest:

```
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Admin's have access to everything.",
        "displayName": "Admin",
        "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-ba4b-6d06b947c66f",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "Admin"
    },
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
       options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
       options.AddPolicy("Packager", policy => policy.RequireRole("Packager"));
    });
```

View:

```
@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "Admin")).Succeeded)
{
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Admin">Admin</a></li>
}
```

EDIT (May 8th):
Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) doc from Microsoft, I got it to work. Added it to my `Startup.cs`:

```
  services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
  {
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
  });
```

Comment: Which .net core version you use?

Comment: My .net core version is 2.1

Answer (score 1):

http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role is the old SAML claim type format. For OIDC Azure AD will issue one or more [roles claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims).

To solve it ensure the following code is in place during service configuration:

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});
```

Comment: The code `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims` can not run in net core 2.1

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the code added in my original post. It is similar to yours, but with AzureAD AuthenticationScheme.